# How do I make it so that my MousePressed listener only respons when I click in a certain area?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I have created a simple GUI that has 2 circles and 2 squares. When the mouse is clicked the shapes change to a random colour. I would like my shapes to only change colour when the mouse has been clicked inside a shape. Also, at the moment all 4 shapes change colour but I wish for each shape to change colour independently depending on which shape is clicked.

```
package weekThree;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class taskTwo2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 200;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private Color circleColor = Color.RED;   //starting colour
    private Color circleColor2 = Color.BLUE;
    private Color squareColor = Color.GREEN;
    private Color squareColor2 = Color.YELLOW;
    private int circX  = 10;
    private int circY = circX;
    private int circW = PREF_W - 2 * circX;
    private int circH = PREF_H - 2 * circY;

    public taskTwo2() {
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse()); //mouse click listener
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // to smooth out graphics
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); //smoothes out edges

        g2.setColor(circleColor);
        g2.fillOval(circX, circY, circW, circH);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawOval(circX, circY, circW, circH);


        g2.setColor(circleColor2);
        g2.fillOval(25*(circX), 25*(circY), circW, circH);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawOval(25*(circX), 25*(circY), circW, circH);


        g2.setColor(squareColor);
        g2.fillRect(circX, 25*(circY), circW, circH);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(circX, 25*(circY), circW, circH);


        g2.setColor(squareColor2);
        g2.fillRect(25*(circX), circY, circW, circH);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(25*(circX), circY, circW, circH);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            float red = rand.nextFloat();       //generates a random value for the red tint value
            float green = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue = rand.nextFloat();
            circleColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            float red2 = rand.nextFloat();
            float green2 = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue2 = rand.nextFloat();
            circleColor2 = new Color(red2, green2, blue2);

            float red3 = rand.nextFloat();
            float green3 = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue3 = rand.nextFloat();
            squareColor = new Color(red3, green3, blue3);

            float red4 = rand.nextFloat();
            float green4 = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue4 = rand.nextFloat();
            squareColor2 = new Color(red4, green4, blue4);

            repaint();   //repaint components
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() { //code for GUI visuals
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTaskToo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new taskTwo2());
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the mouse location in your `mousePressed()` method by using `Point mouseLocation = e.getPoint();` Then you have to check if the mouse is within the bounds of the circle. The equation for this is simply the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from the center of the circle:

```
/**
 * Checks if the mouse location is within the circle
 * @param mouseLocation the location of the mouse
 * @param cX circle center X location
 * @param cY circle center Y location
 * @param cR circle radius
 * @return true if the mouse is no more than cR units away from the center of the circle 
 */
private static boolean isInCircle(Point mouseLocation, double cX, double cY, double cR){
    final double dX = mouseLocation.getX()-cX;
    final double dY = mouseLocation.getY()-cY;
    return Math.sqrt(dX*dX+dY*dY)<=cR;
}
```

Then, you just check each circle. Here's the code for the first one:

```
    if(isInCircle(mouseLocation,circX+circW/2,circY+circH/2,circW/2)){
            float red = rand.nextFloat();       //generates a random value for the red tint value
            float green = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue = rand.nextFloat();
            circleColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        }
```

The code for the squares is similar, but it uses the [Taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).