# Graphical User Inerface

Tags: java, user-interface

So, I am trying to create buttons 8 on left and right side each. And I am really new to GUI. So, I am not sure how to change the colour and shape, to make those buttons a circle and color them in red and blue...This what I have so far...

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

import java.awt.*;

public class Arrangement {

```
// main must be static
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrangement arrangement = new Arrangement();
    arrangement.handle();
}

public void handle() {
    JFrame f= new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());//in the constructor u specify the layout :)
    JPanel a = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());


    JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    JButton b3= new JButton ("Button 3");
    JButton b4= new JButton ("Button 4");
    JButton b5= new JButton ("Button 5");
    JButton b6= new JButton ("Button 6");
    JButton b7 = new JButton("Button 7");
    JButton b8 = new JButton("Button 8");
    JButton b9 = new JButton ("Button 9");
    JButton b10 = new JButton ("Button 10");
    JButton b11 = new JButton ("Button 11");
    JButton b12 =new JButton ("Button 12");
    JButton b13 = new JButton("Button 13");
    JButton b14= new JButton("Button 14");
    JButton b15= new JButton ("Button 15");
    JButton b16 = new JButton ("Button 16");

    GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints d= new GridBagConstraints();

    c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);//spacing

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    p.add(b1,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=2;      
    p.add(b2,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=4;      
    p.add(b3,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=6;      
    p.add(b4,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=8;      
    p.add(b5,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=10;     
    p.add(b6,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=11;     
    p.add(b7,c);

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=12;     
    p.add(b8,c);

    d.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=1;
    a.add(b9,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=2;
    a.add(b10,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=3;
    a.add(b11,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=4;
    a.add(b12,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=6;
    a.add(b13,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=8;
    a.add(b14,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=10;
    a.add(b15,d);

    d.gridx=0;
    d.gridy=12;
    a.add(b16,d);


    f.add(p, BorderLayout.WEST);
    f.add(a, BorderLayout.EAST);

}
```

}
Now the problem here is I cant use "this. ", with static and if I remove static I get an error saying I need to include static for my code to work...
Can someone help me debug this :'( and direct me as to how can I get my buttons to be desired shape and colour...! Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: You can't reference non-static variables from static contexts. What you can do is create an instance of Arrangement and substitute this for your instance reference

Comment: @AbsalonCastañon is right. I give a few more details on this issue below.

Comment: Not really an answer but I suggest that you ***don't*** do awt.*; and swing.*; They both are huge libraries and may slow down the program when you don't need everything there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jack :) Duly noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are three issues with your code.The first one is already discussed. You can't reference non static variables from a static context.

> this word is not static and main method is static

Now, to change background color, effectively you call the  **setBackground()** method on the element you want the color to change.

Finally, to make the shape of the button you can follow this link: 
[Making buttons round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round)

Bassically what you are doing here is extending the jbutton class. Not allowing it to draw its own shape and use graphics to draw on it. 
You can use graphics to draw on every java GUI componnent. All you have to do is to implement de paint componnent method

By the way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631636/what-is-the-correct-path-to-display-an-imageicon-png-file-for-windows-7) is a clearer and simpler way to display image icons.

---

One last comment, the key to make it easier to debug is trying to write clean and organized code.
For example, I can see that you repeat the following code once and again:

```
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=1;
p.add(b1,c);
```

What you can do is create a function to pack it

```
void pack(Insets target, int xCoord,int yCoord,Component comp ){
target.gridx=xCoord;
target.gridy=yCoord;
p.add(comp, target);
}
```

you can create an array with all the buttons too, so you can use a for loop to  **pack** them:

```
JButton[] buttons= new JButton[8];

for(int j=0;j<16;j++){
    buttons[j]= new JButton("Button "+(j+1));
}
```

Packing of left buttons:

```
for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
    pack(c, 0, j+1,buttons[j+1]);
}
```

---

Thi is the final result

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class Arrangement {



public void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f= new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());//in the constructor u specify the layout :)
    JPanel a = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
    Arrangement arr= new Arrangement();
    for(int j=0;j<16;j++){
       if(j==0)
        Image img= new ImageIcon(arr.getClass().getResource("/Red.png")).getImage();
//Supposing you followed the link and created the class
       buttons[j]= new RoundButton("Button "+(j+1));
    }

    GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints d= new GridBagConstraints();

    c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);//spacing

    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
       arr.pack(c, 0, j+1,buttons[j],p);
    }
    d.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
       arr.pack(d, 0, j+9,buttons[j+8],a);
    }


    f.add(p, BorderLayout.WEST);
    f.add(a, BorderLayout.EAST);

}
void pack(Insets target, int xCoord,int yCoord,Component comp, Panel container ){
target.gridx=xCoord;
target.gridy=yCoord;
container.add(comp, target);
}
```

}

Comment: I have edited the code in regards with the first issue, it has been fixed! Thanks for the tagged links I will look into it! Also I am not trying to change the background colour, I am trying to change the colour of the buttons. Thanks tho :)

Comment: I get that, the thing is each componnent has a background color, so  if you want to change the color of a button, you have to change it's background color

Comment: Thank you so much :D! Yeah I was trying to create a for loops as well but kept messing it up :P Thanks for all the time you put in to solve my problem! I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: This is what the community is about. I am sure when your turn comes you will help others as it's meant too

Answer (score 2):

This was too long for a comment, but it relates to your use of the `static` keyword:

The reason you can't use the `this` keyword and must have `static` is because your code is executed in the static `main` method. Instead, move all the code from `main` to a new method in the `Arrangement` class, say it's called `handle()`. Then create an instance of `Arrangement` at the beginning of your main class and call `handle()`. For instance:

```
public class Arrangement {

    // main must be static
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrangement arrangement = new Arrangement();
        arrangement.handle();
    }

    public void handle() {
        /* Put the rest of your code here and 
         * you'll be able to use the 'this' keyword */
    }

}
```

Additional questions that might be helpful:

- [Why can't we use `this` keyword in a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664522/why-cant-we-use-this-keyword-in-a-static-method)
- [What does the `static` keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)
- [Difference between Static methods and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

**EDIT** A similar task was described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385457/how-do-i-make-it-so-that-my-mousepressed-listener-only-respons-when-i-click-in-a/35385945#35385945). The user wanted to have clickable circles and squares display on-screen. Rather than using a `JButton` he simply drew shapes on-screen.

Comment: When I do that....it gives me an error saying "The method handle() is undefined for the type Arrangement"...

Comment: Make sure you save the file and check your spelling.

Comment: Nevermind.Yeah, I got it. Except for the image is still unable to display on the frame. But thanks for your help :) Appreciate it!

Comment: What error do you get? Also, I added a new link to my post

Comment: There is no error. Its just that if I create an instance of Arrangement, and follow on to use "this" keyword, all my buttons disappear and my frame is a blank...Oh and also thanks for the link! I will look into it rn!

Answer (score 1):

use can use custom icons for your button as

`jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\image.jpg"));`

if you want to set color to button then use following code

```
    jButton1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    jButton1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
```

hope my code helps you in this regard.

Comment: When I try out the first suggestion it gives me a blank screen, and i am guessing the setBackground is supposed to set the blackground color and setForeground will change the color of the text written on the button, for that cause. What I am trying to do is change the color and shape of the whole button itself. Thanks for the help anyways...

Comment: then its better to use set icon method create your own .jpg files and place them on the button using above syntax that  really works for me may be you should give it a try once i should arn you in this context that image dont make your imabe too big use appropriate sizes of images for the button hope this helps

Comment: Yeah! I resized the image! I am not sure what the problem was. But I ended up creating new shapes. But thanks for the input, :) I greatly appreciate it :D